# Convert each multilinestring to one linestring only

Tags: geopandas, r-sf, multilinestring

In this [shapefile](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tQgpXH9M8KpKu5RLqpXNqSCLzvWY-jVT?usp=sharing), the geometry column is linestring apart from 4 stream reaches (`8168547, 8171738, 8170616 ,8169920`) that are multilinestring.

[image]

I need to convert each multilinestring to one linestring only .
I have tried many things but none worked. For example, I tried `st_cast` in sf package in R. However, it increased the number of the rows (it converts each multilinestring to several linestrings).

How can I convert each multilinestring to one linestring only?

Comment: May I ask, **why** do you want them as single LINESTRINGS?

Comment: @SymbolixAU
It is a good question. I should have mentioned that above. 
There is a python package I'm using that requires all features in the shapefile to be linestring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in geopandas, this can be done with [`explode`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html):

```py
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file(filepath)
exploded = gdf.explode()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `{sf}` way of converting multilinestrings to linestrings would be, as you mention, via `sf::st_cast()`.

But there is a problem with your data - some of the streams are not possible to make into simple linestrings. A linestring must have a single start and a single end point - this is simply not possible for some of your rchids. As a result some of your objects end up being duplicated.

As this is a general failure - and not a R specific one - I would expect the comment to be valid also for geopandas, although I have not ran the code to verify.

I suggest first casting your object to linestrings, then identifying duplicites and filtering them out.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

streams <- st_read("tukituki_rivStrah3.shp") %>% 
  select(-length) %>% # filtering out, as length is a derived metric
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

duplicities <- streams %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() %>% 
  group_by(rchid) %>% 
  tally %>% 
  filter(n > 1) %>% 
  pull(rchid)

# this will not do...
mapview::mapview(streams[streams$rchid == duplicities[2],])
```

[image]

```
clean_streams <- streams %>% 
  filter(!rchid %in% duplicities)
```

Answer (score 1):

In geopandas you can merge linesegments. If your multilinestring is clean, segments have the same direction and they are properly sorted. You can try something like that:

(But probably you have to clean your segments first :))

```python
...
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
...

def multiline_to_single_line(geometry: Union[LineString, MultiLineString]) -> LineString:
  if isinstance(geometry, LineString):
      return geometry
  coords = list(map(lambda part: list(part.coords), geometry.geoms))
  flat_coords = [Point(*point) for segment in coords for point in segment]
  return LineString(flat_coords)

gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].apply(multiline_to_single_line)
```